# How are these two properties of Conformal Killing Vectors compatible?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, vector-fields, conformal-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a semi-Riemannian manifold. A Conformal Killing Vector (CKV) $Y$ is any vector field obeying the Conformal Killing Equation: $$\nabla_\mu Y_\nu+\nabla_\nu Y_\mu=g_{\mu\nu}\dfrac{2}{d} \nabla\cdot Y,\quad \nabla\cdot Y\equiv \nabla_\mu Y^\mu\tag{1}.$$

Contracting the equation with $\nabla^\mu\nabla^\nu$ and using the Riemann tensor I found this equation can be written as
$$\left(2-\frac{2}{d}\right)\Box(\nabla\cdot Y)+\nabla^\mu (R^{\nu}_{\phantom{\nu}\rho\nu\mu}Y^\rho)+\nabla^\nu (R^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\rho\nu\mu}Y^\rho)+R^{\nu}_{\phantom \nu \rho \mu\nu}\nabla^\rho Y^\mu+R^{\mu}_{\phantom \mu \rho \mu\nu}\nabla^\nu Y^\rho=0,\quad \Box \equiv \nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu\tag{2}$$

In maximally symmetric spaces, using the form of $R^\sigma_{\phantom{\sigma}\rho\mu\nu}$, I managed to show that $$\Box(\nabla\cdot Y)=0.\tag{3}$$

This seems to be a very general property of CKVs.

Now let us consider the sphere $(S^2,\gamma)$ with round metric $\gamma$. We shall denote the indices with uppercase latin letters and let $D$ be the Levi-Civita connection. Also I write $D^2$ for $\Box$. In the analysis of the $\mathfrak{bms}_4$ algebra there appears one such CKV $Y$ on $S^2$. In trying to reproduce the results from the literature I came to a point in which to obtain the known results it would be necessary to employ $$D^2(D\cdot Y)=-2D\cdot Y\tag{4}.$$

Now it would seem that this is impossible in view of (3). If $Y$ is a CKV the LHS of (4) *must be zero* since $(S^2,\gamma)$ is maximally symmetric!

It turns out, however, that there is mention to (4) in the literature. For example in the solutions section of "[Lectures on the IR Structure of Gravity and Gauge Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448)", in page (132) it is said right bellow Eq. (9.0.180)

> Note that $$\gamma^{AB}\delta C_{AB} = \frac{u}{2}(-4D\cdot Y-2D^2D\cdot Y)+C^{AB}(D_AY_B+D_BY_A)=0,\tag{9.0.181}$$ **where $\pmb{D^2D\cdot Y=-2D\cdot Y}$**, and $C^{AB}(D_AY_B+D_BY_A)=C^{AB}\gamma_{AB}D\cdot Y$. Hence, $C_{AB}$ remains traceless under the diffeomorphism generated by $\zeta$.

So now I'm quite confused because this is saying that (4) is true. But since $Y$ is a CKV (3) should be true and both are incompatible unless $D\cdot Y=0$ which is certainly not the case in general.

What am I missing here? I am quite sure I'm missing something *very basic* here. Is this some issue with notation, so that the LHS of (4) *is not the same* as the LHS of (3)? What is the actual relation between (3) and (4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Equation (2), and hence Equation (3), is incorrect.  The correct version of Equation (2) is
$$ \left( 2 - \frac{2}{d}\right)\Box(\nabla\cdot Y)+ 2\nabla^\mu\left(R^\nu{}_{\rho\nu\mu}Y^\rho\right) + R^\nu{}_{\rho\mu\nu}\nabla^\rho Y^\mu + R^\mu{}_{\rho\mu\nu}\nabla^\nu Y^\rho = 0 . $$
For what it's worth, this immediately simplifies to
$$ \left(2-\frac{2}{d}\right)\Box(\nabla\cdot Y) + 2\nabla^\mu(R_{\rho\mu}Y^\rho) $$
on all pseudo-Riemannian manifolds, which is a much nicer formula to look at.  Evaluating on the two-sphere is now consistent with your Equation (4).

Comment: thanks very much for the help, it's been two days trying to find the mistake ! In the end the issue is that in one of the steps I have misplaced the indices of the Riemann tensor and exchanged $\mu\leftrightarrow \nu$. Since I got agreement with the flat space case I ended up thinking the calculation was right, but it was in fact wrong ! You were very helpful